# Linear Transformation from one function to another.

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-analysis

Let's say we have two functions $f:[-1,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g:[-1,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Suppose furthermore that one can write down $f,g$ in terms of a linear sum of basis functions that span the domain $[-1,1]$ (like Fourier Series)

$$
f(x) = \sum_n a_ne^{i\omega_n x} \\
g(x) = \sum_mb_me^{i\omega_m x}
$$

Does there exist a matrix $M_{nm}$ that transforms $f(x)$ to $g(x)$? Do there exist some functions where a linear transformation $M:f\rightarrow g$ cannot exist? Under the case where this kind of transformation is possible, how would one compute $M$?

Comment: "Does there exist a matrix $M$ that transforms $f$...": what do you mean by a matrix transforming a function?

Comment: Are the sums finite or infinite?

Comment: To Greg Martin, I mean $g = M*f$ where $*$ is some linear transformation. My thinking is that, since you can write down functions in terms of basis functions that span a function space, there must exist some kind of linear transformation that takes you from one function to another.  

To user7530, I am considering the most general case, so the consider the series to be infinite. If it cannot be infinite, why not? How would one do this if the series is finite?

Answer (score 0):

We can easily create a linear transformation between vector spaces that maps the vector $\{a_n\}$ to the vector $ \{b_m\}$, but in general this will *not* translate into a linear transformation in function space i.e. this does not mean that $g$ is a linear function of $f$.

Comment: When would $g$ be a linear function in $f$?

Comment: @firest The function $g$ is only a linear function of $f$ if $b_k = \lambda a_k$ where the constant $\lambda$ is the *same* for all $k$ between $0$ and $\min(m,n)$.

Comment: This seems too restrictive. I mean, don't there exist transformations of one set of orthogonal polynomials to another within a specific domain (like Chebyshev to Jacobi)?